# Swipe Between Two UIViews

Tags: objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer

How can I swipe between two UIViews using Pan Gesture Handler with Swift?

I would like to be able to swipe left and begin to reveal the next UIView, but snap back if the gesture isn't complete (to a certain point).

Currently using Swipe Gesture (but it doesn't animate and show preview halfway through)

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            println("Swiped right")
            loadView1()
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            println("Swiped left")
            loadView2()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the gesture start revealing the next UIView and snap back if the gesture isn't complete?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the start and end position of your swipe and load the different views if the distance isn't long enough:

```
var startLocation:CGPoint!
var endLocation:CGPoint!

if(gesture.state == .Began){
    startLocation = gesture.locationInView(self.view)
} else if(gesture.state == .Ended){
    endLocation = gesture.locationInView(self.view)  
    var distance = endLocation.x - startLocation.x
}
```